# Iteration over a predefined cursor vs generating a cursor in for loop

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

There are 2 ways to read data from mongo using pymongo.
The first create a cursor and assign it to python variable and iterate over the variable using for loop.
i.e.

```
mongo_cursor = db[collection_name].find().batch_size()
for data in mongo_cursor:
     print data
```

The other approach is to skip the variable part.
i.e.

```
for data in db[collection_name].find().batch_size(100):
     print data
```

I suppose both are one and the same thing, but at times I have found the latter approach to be faster than first one.

Is there some logical explanation for this?

PS: I know how batch_size works and both are altogether same approches, just want to know anyone else has ever faced performance gains while using second way.

Comment: First of all, those are NOT "two different ways" and are really the same thing. Second, `batch_size` does not do what you seem to think it does, but it will mean that "more results" are taken from the server at a time. It really depends on the data being read as to how effective it can be, so there is not really a "general" answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn Agreed but my question is regarding performance Since both are same ways to iterate and given that I have provided the same batch_size the question is why the second one is faster and not the first one.